# combine two charts into the single PDF using ReportLab?

Tags: python, django, reportlab

I'm using Django and Reportlabs to generate reports in PDF. I'm referring to [this tutorial](https://code.djangoproject.com/wiki/Charts).

I read [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9339572/how-to-combine-two-charts-into-the-single-pdf-using-reportlab) as well as [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9696211/python-how-to-make-reportlab-move-to-next-page-in-pdf-output) also  which says use `canv.showpage()` and then I'll be able to combine 2 charts in 1 pdf, but still I get only that chart which comes second in the code, in my case only line graph.

How can I save 2 charts in 1 pdf?

Here is my code.

```
import barchart
import linechart
from django.http import HttpResponse
from reportlab.graphics.shapes import Drawing
from reportlab.graphics.charts.barcharts import VerticalBarChart
from reportlab.graphics import renderPDF    
from reportlab.pdfgen import canvas


def generate_report(request):


    #instantiate a drawing object
    canv = canvas.Canvas('output.pdf')#,pagesize=LETTER) 
    canv.setPageCompression(0)  
    d = barchart.MyBarChartDrawing()

    #extract the request params of interest.
    #I suggest having a default for everything.
    if 'height' in request:
        d.height = int(request['height'])
    if 'width' in request:
        d.width = int(request['width'])

    if 'numbers' in request:
        strNumbers = request['numbers']
        numbers = map(int, strNumbers.split(','))    
        d.chart.data = [numbers]   #bar charts take a list-of-lists for data

    if 'title' in request:
        d.title.text = request['title']


    #get a GIF (or PNG, JPG, or whatever)
    binaryStuff = d.asString('pdf')

    #binaryStuff.save()
    #return HttpResponse(binaryStuff, 'image/pdf')
    #instantiate a drawing object
    canv.showPage()
    a = linechart.MyLineChartDrawing()

    #extract the request params of interest.
    #I suggest having a default for everything.


    a.height = 300
    a.chart.height = 300


    a.width = 300
    a.chart.width = 300

    a.title._text = request.session.get('Some custom title')



    a.XLabel._text = request.session.get('X Axis Labell')
    a.YLabel._text = request.session.get('Y Axis Label')

    a.chart.data = [((1,1), (2,2), (2.5,1), (3,3), (4,5)),((1,2), (2,3), (2.5,2), (3.5,5), (4,6))]



    labels =  ["Label One","Label Two"]
    if labels:
        # set colors in the legend
        a.Legend.colorNamePairs = []
        for cnt,label in enumerate(labels):
            a.Legend.colorNamePairs.append((a.chart.lines[cnt].strokeColor,label))


    #get a GIF (or PNG, JPG, or whatever)
    binaryStuff1 = a.asString('pdf')
    canv.showPage()
    return HttpResponse(binaryStuff, 'pdf')
```

The barchart and linechart code is same from [this site](https://code.djangoproject.com/wiki/Charts).

How would I save in one pdf file only?

Comment: I am assuming that `binaryStuff1 = a.asString('pdf')` should actually be `binaryStuff = a.asString('pdf')`

Answer (score 0):

Based on the code provided, you are getting only the Line Chart because you are only passing BinaryStuff to the response (look at the last 3 lines of your code).

Try creating the graphs as images, drawing the images to the canvas, then returning the canvas as a PDF.

Comment: Please reply to this thread. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20343382/pyrhon-reportlabs-save-2-different-graphs-in-2-different-pages. Thanks